# How do I get all the fields of an order?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, magic-getter

I'm working with Magento, I have orders and I print them like this:

```
echo $order->getId();
echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
```

My problem is that I don't know all the name of the get methods so how or where can I find all the list of get available?

My goal is export all the orders in an external database, is there a faster way to do it without pass for each field?

Comment: take a look in `sales_flat_order` table, all field can be accessed via `getFieldName ` (or `getData('field_name')`)

and open the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` doc block help you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data on the order (or any object) is being held in a protected member variable `_data` which is an array. This data comes from the database table(s) (it is being filled by the resource model).

### Data array

You can get this array and dump it via:

```
print_r($order->getData());
// or
var_dump($order->getData());
```

You will get an output like this with `print_r()`:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 2
    [state] => new
    [status] => pending
// ...
```

### Getters

Now you can get all of this data with Magento object's magic getters. Each value is retrievable in the form of `$object->getValue()` where `Value` is the camel cased version of the key from the array.

For the above values use:

```
$order->getEntityId();
$order->getState();
$order->getStatus();
```

And for `customer_id` for example you can call `$order->getCustomerId()`

### Overrides

The getters can be overridden. The getters construction is defined in the `Varien_Object` class and each Magento model could override a magic getter method by explicitly defining a method. So you should also check the methods of the model by looking at the code or use hinting in your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply print all available field in your object with:

```
print_r($order->getData())
```

Comment: ok, i used it  and  it shows a lot of fields but not all that i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Orders are not stored in an EAV format so all the data is in a flat table.  By loading a `sales/order` model instance you load a row from the `sales_flat_order` table so any column you see here, you can pull from the order object, i.e to pull the `increment_id` column, you can call `$order->getIncrementId()`.  Also be aware that there are some methods in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class object to build a certain amount of data for you, for instance `getCustomerName()` which returns the customer name but does not relate to a `customer_name` column in the `sales_flat_order` table .

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
foreach($order->getData() as $key => $value)
{
  //$key;
  //$value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An one line solution:

```
array_keys($order->getData())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
 $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');  
 /**
  * Get the table name
  */
 $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales/order');

 $saleafield=$readConnection->describeTable($tableName);
 var_dump($saleafield);
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245862/get-all-field-names-from-magento-model